# The letters in an UISegmentedControl seem to deteriorate

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios5

[image]

Consider the above screen shots

The upper most one was generated when the program starts with an initial alpha property set at 0.86 in IB.  The middle one is the same UISegmentedControl with its alpha property set to  the same value by the following message call at runtime.

```
[segmented_control setAlpha : 0.86];
```

And the lowest one is the same control set to 1.00 at runtime as follows.

```
[segmented_control setAlpha : 1.00];
```

It seems that the setAlpha call only works well at 1.00 since the letters in the middle screen shot seem to deteriorate at any values less than 1.

My question is, is there any way to set the control's alpha property less than one and yet retain its display quality ?

Have tried to toggle with the "setOpaque", "setHidden" calls and changing the alpha value to other numbers but the problem persists. Since it can be done in IB (as shown in the top screen shot), so I guess it could be done in code also.  Hope that somebody can give me some hints on this ...

Answer (score 0):

Try acting on the opacity property of the CALayer of the control.

```
theControl.layer.opacity = 0.86;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Have tried the .opacity = 0.86 statement, unfortunately it doesn't work.  The result is the same as the second screen shot above.  Have also tried a "setNeedsDisplay" call right after the .opacity statement and the result is the same.

Comment: @Stanley : You're welcome. I would have like to help you solve your problem.